# C# error: CS1929 does not contain a definition for 'Contains'

Tags: c#, linq

i have been trying to solve this problem but i cant figure it out

My code:

```
var languageWithC = languages.Where(Names => Names.Contains("C#"));
        
foreach (var c in languageWithC)
{
    return c.Prettify();
}
```

```
public Language(int year, string name, string chiefDeveloper, string predecessors)
    {
      Year = year;
      Name = name;
      ChiefDeveloper = chiefDeveloper;
      Predecessors = predecessors;
    }
```

These are included in the top:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

Cant figure it out any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Language is a class and languages is a List code:                                                              List<Language> languages = File.ReadAllLines("./languages.tsv")
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(line => Language.FromTsv(line))
        .ToList();

Comment: Add the code for the `Language` class to your question

Comment: What part of the message is unclear - the `Language` class doesn't contain a `Contains` method.

Comment: This question is becoming a train-wreck in slow-motion

Comment: By the way: You are aware that `return` immediately returns from the function after the first item you processed without processing the others ...

Comment: It is no good practice to use images of code, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). However, I updated my answer - it should work. What @derpirscher said is true as well.

Comment: Sorry guys i am new and found linq very confusing

Comment: Linq is a beast to get used to - but once it "clicks", it will be a powerful tool and quite easy to use.

Comment: @derpirscher is this the correct way to do it: foreach (var c in languageWithC)
        {
         Console.WriteLine($"{c.Prettify()}");
        }

Comment: @MostafaBaker That depends on what you want to do. If you just want to printout then this might ok. If you need the prettified text somewhere else you might be better of with something like `var prettified = languageWithC.Select(x => x.Prettify())` which will return an enumeration of whatever the result of `Prettify()` is

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher yes i am trying to print the result to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to access the property "Name" of your language in your Where-Query. You get the language-object passed into your linq-expression and need to access it's property, not just use the name of the property. The syntax for this is:

```
var languageWithC = languages.Where(language => language.Name == "C#");
```

Comment: You have my money +1 EDIT. i take my money back

Comment: Thanks for the quick help, i have tried that but still get the same error

Comment: Than please add the definition of the "Names"-property to your question, otherwise we can only guess what's wrong.

Comment: @Compufreak Is it ok if i temporarily uncheck your solution? I want to find out why .Contains() is not working, because i have been using it in a simillar fashion and i really want to find out why it is not working.

Comment: You probably used it on a list of strings (or a list containing lists of strings), not on a list of complex objects.

Comment: @Compufreak Yes you are right, if i create the objects it should work?